# GLM LookAt with different coordinate system

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions, glm-math

I am using GLM to make a LookAt matrix. I use the normal OpenGL coordinate system, but with the Z axis going inwards which is the opposite of the OpenGL standard. Thus, the LookAt function requires some changes:

```cpp
glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0, 0, -10); // equal to glm::vec3(0, 0, 10) in standard coords
glm::quat rot = glm::vec3(0.991445, 0.130526, 0, 0); // 15 degrees rotation about the x axis
glm::vec3 resultPos = pos * glm::vec3(1, 1, -1); // flip Z axis
glm::vec3 resultLook = pos + (glm::conjugate(rot) * glm::vec3(0, 0, 1)) * glm::vec3(1, 1, -1); // rotate unit Z vec and then flip Z
glm::vec3 resultUp = (glm::conjugate(rot) * glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)) * glm::vec3(1, 1, -1); // same thing as resultLook but with unit Y vec
glm::mat4 lookAt = glm::lookAt(resultPos, resultLook, resultUp)
```

However, that is a lot of calculation for just flipping a single axis. What do I need to do to get a view matrix which has a flipped Z axis?

Comment: Yes, my coordinates are in a LHS. I've tried scaling it but it warps everything in a way that I can't really describe.

Comment: Do you build the view mat like so: `glm::translate(glm::mat4_cast(rot), pos)`? so your fix would be `glm::scale(glm::translate(glm::mat4_cast(rot), pos), glm::vec3(1, 1, -1))`?

Comment: I don't really want to use lookAt because I need to calculate three vectors each frame. Is there not a way to convert the `rot` quaternion into a matrix then flip it?